# Existing record in php

Tags: php, postgresql

Whenever I add a new place/description in my UI, it will save automatically to my database. My problem is that I can still add a place eventhough it's already existing. All I want is that it won't save/update a new description/place if it's already exist.

Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

This is my my EditPlaces:

```
public function executeEditPlaces(sfWebRequest $request)
{
 try{
 $id  = pg_escape_string(strip_tags($request->getParameter("id")));

 // $id  = $request->getParameter("id");
 $query = "select description from country.regions where id = ('$id')";
    // die($query);


    $result=$this->conn->fetchAll($query);

    if(count($result)>0){

    $v = $result[0];
    $data['data'] = array('description' => $this->formatString($v['description']));
    }


    $data['success']=true;
    $data['msg']=$msg;
    die(json_encode($data));

  }
  catch(exception $e)
  {     
    $data['success']=false;
    $data['msg']=$e->getMessage();
    die(json_encode($data));
  }
}
```

This is my UpdatePlaces:

```
public function executeUpdatePlaces(sfWebRequest $request)
{
 try{
 $by = $_SESSION['employee_id'];
 $now = date("Y-m-d H:I:s");

 $id  = $request->getParameter("id");
 $description  = pg_escape_string(strip_tags($request->getParameter("description")));

$description = trim($description);

 if(strlen($description) == 0)
 {
    die('cannot be empty');
 }  
 else
    {

$query = "update country.regions set description=('$description'),modified_by=('$by'),date_modified=('$now') where id=('$id')";

    $msg = "Existing Region Successfully Updated.";


    $this->conn->execute($query);
    $data['success']=true;
    $data['msg']=$msg;
    die(json_encode($data));
    }
  }
  catch(exception $e)
  {     
    $data['success']=false;
    $data['msg']=$e->getMessage();
    die(json_encode($data));
  }     

}
```

Comment: Change your DB schema with the `unique` constraint.

Comment: Yes, simply define description/place as unique indexes.

Comment: @davidkonrad where do I have to define a unique indexes?

Comment: @Mikel, see user1168095 answer below. I suggest you use a tool like PHPMyadmin, where creating indexes is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two way:

1. You can alter your table so the column is unique

   ALTER IGNORE TABLE country.regions ADD UNIQUE (description);
2. Check if your description/place already exist using a select

   ```
   $query = "select description from country.regions";
   $result=$this->conn->fetchAll($query);
   if(count($result)>0){
       print 'already exist'  
   } else {
       //insert code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if `$description` of duplicated entries are really the same.

You may introduce `UNIQUE` constraint to SQL schema for the columns that must be unique - it will introduce security in the lower layer.

Please check if description is of type `bytea`. If yes, `pg_escape_bytea` should be used instead of `pg_escape_string`.